# How do I get the files from SFTP server and move them to another folder in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, sftp

How do I get the one by one files from SFTP server and move them to another folder in Ubuntu bash script?

```
#!bin/sh
FOLDER=/home/SFTP/Folder1/    

sftp SFTP@ip_address    
cd /home/FSTP/Folder1/    
for file in "$FOLDER"*
<<EOF
cd /home/local/Folder1
get $file
EOF
mv $file /home/SFTP/Done
done
```

I know it's not right, but I've tried my best and if anyone can help me, I will appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSH `sftp` is not very powerful client for such tasks. You would have to run it twice. First to collect list of files, use the list to generate list of commands, and execute those in a second run.

Something like this:

```
# Collect list of files
files=`sftp -b - user@example.com <<EOF
cd /source/folder
ls
EOF`
files=`echo $files|sed "s/.*sftp> ls//"` 

# Use the list to generate list of commands for the second run
(
  echo cd /source/folder
  for file in $files; do
    echo get $file
    echo rename $file /backup/folder/$file
  done
) | sftp -b - user@example.com
```

---

Before you run the script on production files, I suggest, you first output the generated command list to a file to check, if the results are as expected.

Just replace the last line with:

```
) > commands.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use SFTP internal command.

```
sftp get -r $remote_path $local_path
```

OR with the -f option to flush files to disk

```
sftp get -rf $remote_path $local_path
```

Answer (score -1):

Use rsync https://rsync.samba.org/

rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST:DEST

```
rsync SFTP@ip_address:/home/FSTP/Folder1/* /home/SFTP/Done/
```

To move files add option --remove-source-files

```
rsync --remove-source-files SFTP@ip_address:/home/FSTP/Folder1/* /home/SFTP/Done/
```

Comment: How does this answer the "move" part of the question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I was not very precise. 
You can pass --remove-source-files to rsync to move files instead of copying them.

rsync  --remove-source-files SFTP@ip_address:/home/FSTP/Folder1/* /home/SFTP/Done/

Comment: The question asks for *"mov[ing] them to another [remote] folder"*.

Comment: The question literally asks, "How do I get the one by one files from SFTP server and move them to another folder in Ubuntu bash script?" 

Move files from server to local folder, not remote folder.

Even with a remote folder, it is possible with rsync:


rsync --remove-source-files SFTP@ip_address:/home/FSTP/Folder1/* SFTP@remote_ip:/home/SFTP/Done/

Comment: I'm not sure we understand each other. In the question that there imo three folders, the local target folder – `/home/local/Folder1`, remote source folder –  `/home/FSTP/Folder1/` and remote archive folder – `/home/SFTP/Done`. I can see only two folders in your answer.